# Crispy Fields not working but Crispy Form does

Tags: python, django, forms, django-crispy-forms, modelform

I'm not sure why this is happening but...

When I layout my Django ModelForm, if I do {{ form | crispy }} everything goes as planned.

If I try to do each individual field like, {{ form.city|as_crispy_field }} everything renders correctly, I get "POST /management/edit_gamelines/197/ HTTP/1.1" 200 28761" in the terminal but the form doesn't submit.

Any ideas?

I appreciate the help :)

Comment: Show the relevant form, view and template...

Comment: you may forget to render hidden field.